# How to create an HTML page that refreshes in real time using Python?

Tags: python, html, user-interface

This is a simple data visualization task that I am trying to accomplish: seeing data in real time using my web browser.

My idea is to take an HTML template and change only a few key values inside of it once a second using Python. I need it to be HTML and not something else like pygtk because CSS formatting is very practical for my application.

Is that possible? What would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

the Flask module should solve your problems

Comment: If it could be helped in a comment, istead of posting an answer, try writing comment instead. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript setInterval and XHR.
See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
https://makitweb.com/how-to-fire-ajax-request-on-regular-interval/

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX updates part of webpage in realtime without refreshing the whole page.**

using Ajax in Django is to use the Django Ajax framework.

The most commonly used is django-dajax which is a powerful tool to easily and super-quickly develop asynchronous presentation logic in web applications, using Python and almost no JavaScript source code. It supports four of the most popular Ajax frameworks: Prototype, jQuery, Dojo and MooTools.

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_ajax.htm#:~:text=Using%20Ajax%20in%20Django%20can,library%20like%20JQuery%20or%20others.&text=The%20most%20commonly%20used%20is,almost%20no%20JavaScript%20source%20code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_ajax.htm#:%7E:text=Using%20Ajax%20in%20Django%20can,library%20like%20JQuery%20or%20others.&text=The%20most%20commonly%20used%20is,almost%20no%20JavaScript%20source%20code).